# Как добавить условие в ON?

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql

Никак не получается добавить условие в on для зависимости
Имеется такая модель:

```php
class Parent extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getChild()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class, ['parent_id' => 'parent_id'])->alias('c');
    }
}
```

Получаю данные так:

```php
$query = Parent::find()
    ->alias('p')
    ->distinct()
    ->joinWith([
        'child c'
    ], true, 'inner join');
```

В итоге запрос получается примерно такой:

```sql
select 
  p.* 
from parent p
inner join child c 
  on c.parent_id = p.parent_id
```

Вопрос в том, что я никак не могу сообразить как получить такой запрос:

```sql
select 
  p.* 
from parent p
inner join child c 
  on c.parent_id = p.parent_id and c.is_disabled = false
```

Comment: в where я конечно-же могу добавить, но результат выполнения запроса будет не тот, который необходим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация по ActiveQuery решила проблему\
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#onCondition()-detail

```
class Parent extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getChild()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class, ['parent_id' => 'parent_id'])
            ->alias('c')
            ->onCondition('c.is_disabled = false');
    }
};
```